# Using background processes to optimize script for speed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

all,

I have this bash shell scripting project I'm working on where I run a number of processes in a loop to extract a value from a text. I feel that I could get the program to run faster using the & operator to run the processes in the background.

Thing is, I think I have the code right for doing what I want to do, but when I run it, it takes as long as if I didn't use the & and curly braces. Before I go tweaking for efficiency, I wanted to see if anyone could help point me in the right direction.

The code in particular is this:

```
while read line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do

{ convert "$line" "$dotdec" "10"
convert "$line" "$dothex" "16"
convert "$line" "$dotoct" "8"
convert "$line" "$dotbin" "2"
convert "$line" "$bin" "2"
convert "$line" "$oct" "8"
convert "$line" "$hex" "16"
convert "$line" "$dec" "10" & }

done < $1

wait
echo -e "$values" | sort | uniq -d | sort -nr | head -1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look into [`gnu parallel`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Comment: Where does `$values` get set?

Comment: $values is set within the convert command.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
{ convert "$line" "$dotdec" "10"
convert "$line" "$dothex" "16"
convert "$line" "$dotoct" "8"
convert "$line" "$dotbin" "2"
convert "$line" "$bin" "2"
convert "$line" "$oct" "8"
convert "$line" "$hex" "16"
convert "$line" "$dec" "10" & }

done < $1

wait
```

by

```
convert "$line" "$dotdec" "10" &
convert "$line" "$dothex" "16" &
convert "$line" "$dotoct" "8" &
convert "$line" "$dotbin" "2" &
convert "$line" "$bin" "2" &
convert "$line" "$oct" "8" &
convert "$line" "$hex" "16" &
convert "$line" "$dec" "10" &
wait
done < $1
```

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't give me any output when I changed that, and it still took over the desired time. I'm wondering if there's something wrong in the convert functions.

Comment: If `convert` isn't very complex, it is quite possible that your `while read` loop is what's dominating the running time. Try splitting the input to a bunch of smaller files and run parallel jobs on each chunk instead, where each job can be internally serial.

Comment: Maybe put the `wait` outside the loop?

Answer (score 1):

In you example, you just put the latest command `convert "$line" "$dec" "10" &` to the background.

If all the command need to be executed in the order, you can chain all the commands with the `&&` operation and put them to background in a sub process.

```
( convert "$line" "$dotdec" "10" &&
convert "$line" "$dothex" "16" &&
convert "$line" "$dotoct" "8" &&
convert "$line" "$dotbin" "2" &&
convert "$line" "$bin" "2" &&
convert "$line" "$oct" "8" &&
convert "$line" "$hex" "16" &&
convert "$line" "$dec" "10" & )
```

here is another simple example, the following command will return shortly after executed.

```
for i in `seq 10`;do (sleep $i && echo sleep $i &);done
```

Answer (score 0):

As per @RedX recommendation, with [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) the code might look like that (assuming that the expanded variables have no spaces in them):

```
while read line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do

    echo convert "$line" "$dotdec" "10"
    echo convert "$line" "$dothex" "16"
    echo convert "$line" "$dotoct" "8"
    echo convert "$line" "$dotbin" "2"
    echo convert "$line" "$bin" "2"
    echo convert "$line" "$oct" "8"
    echo convert "$line" "$hex" "16"
    echo convert "$line" "$dec" "10"

done < $1 | parallel :::
```

This is the simplest way to use the `parallel`. By default (or with `:::` as an argument), `parallel` reads the commands to be run from the stdin, runs them in parallel, and waits for them to finish. Without explicit `-j` option, `parallel` would run simultaneously only one job per physical CPU/core. If any command exists with non-zero status, `parallel` would indicate that with exit status 1.

As an alternative, I often convert the shell scripts into `Makefile`s which can be then run with `make -j`. Although that required more work, it allows to put little more advanced shell commands into `Makefile`s, and have more control over the error handling.